# How to get multiple attribute(array) of a product (array) in the Product page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm kind of noob so forgive me if you think the question is rudimental.

```
 $product = Products::where('product_slug', $slug)->first();  
 // the products page where products are displayed by using @foreach and @endforeach

 $product_attributes = ProductAttribute::all()->where('SKU_code', $product->SKU_code);  
 //this control the attributes of each product like price,
```

How to display both product and attribute, showing the available sizes of each product in the same foreach loop ?

Comment: What have you coded so far? Do you get any errors? Does something not work?

Answer (score 0):

First you should define a relation in `Product` model:

```
function product_attributes() {
    return $this-hasMany(ProductAttribute::class); // assuming that product_attributes table has product_id column in it.
}
```

In controller get products with all attributes:

```
// with product_attributes (name of the relation)
$products = Product::where('product_slug',$slug)->with('product_attributes')->get();
```

You can filter what attributes to include from your relation, for eg.

```
$products = Product::where('product_slug',$slug)->with(['product_attributes'=>function($query) {
    $query->where('attribute_name','product_size');
])->get();
```

later on, in blade:

```
@foreach($products as $product)  
    {{$product->name}}
    // don't use product_attributes() because it will make a query for each product! 
    // use it without parthanees
    @foreach($product->product_attributes as $attribute) 
        {{$attribute->name}}:  {{$attribute->value}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Check [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) for more info about relations and how to query them.